# SQL JS Bulk INsert

Tags: javascript, sql

```js
        
        var elements = [{
            "name": "1",
            "age": 11
        }, {
            "name": "2",
            "age": 22
        }, {
            "name": 3,
            "age": 33
        }, {
            "name": 4,
            "age": 44
        }, {
            "name": 5,
            "age": 55
        }, {
            "name": null,
            "age": 66
        }];
        let vals = elements.map(Object.values).map(a => "(" + a + ")").join(",");


      const insert_into_download_list_table_sql = `INSERT INTO DOWNLOAD_LIST(DOWNLOAD_DATE,COLO) VALUES ${vals}`;
      console.log(insert_into_download_list_table_sql);
```

An error occurs even thou the sql is well formatted so i'm not sure why it's not working .

```
   db.transaction(function (tx) {
          tx.executeSql(insert_into_download_list_table_sql, [],
              function (tx2, results2) {   
                  console.log({results2})
              }, app.onError);
      });
```

When i run the code i get an sql insert statement

```
INSERT INTO DOWNLOAD_LIST(DOWNLOAD_DATE,COLO) VALUES (1,11),(2,22),(3,33),(4,44),(5,55),(,66)
```

DB Error: near ",":syntax error

```
  [SqlTransaction] id: 18, connectionId: 1. | Error occured while executing sql: INSERT INTO DOWNLOAD_LIST(DOWNLOAD_DATE,COLO) VALUES (1,11),(2,22),(3,33),(4,44),(5,55),(,66). Error: [object Object]
```

Comment: maybe the `null` value does not fit. where is the error pointing to?

Comment: DB Error: near ",":syntax error; I removed the null but still same :(

Comment: Can it be the commas inside the parenthesis?

Comment: I think WEB SQL DB is not supporting bulk insert 's